# jQuery DataTables 'OR' Search/ Filter

Tags: jquery, search, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables (http://www.datatables.net/) to display some tabular data. The search/ filter is a powerful feature. Although if multiple keywords are searched in the table the search filters only the already filtered data.

For instance in the example here - http://jsfiddle.net/illuminatus/2j0Lz5or/1/

If the keywords are searched like `10 99` it does not yield any result. I want the search to display all the results/ rows containing all the keyword which are searched or entered.

Searching `10 99` would display rows 1, 5 and 6.

Technically, the search should be an 'OR' search.

Would appreciate any help.

EDIT:
The search should be an 'OR' search.

Comment: you can also use my yadcf plugin  (multiple filter) http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_source_chosen.html (see first column)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**AND**-filter (include rows where all search words is present).
This [custom filter](http://datatables.net/development/filtering) overrides the builtin filtering process. Each column in each row is compared with each search word.

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
  function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
      var keywords = $(".dataTables_filter input").val().split(' ');  
      var matches = 0;
      for (var k=0; k<keywords.length; k++) {
          var keyword = keywords[k];
          for (var col=0; col<aData.length; col++) {
              if (aData[col].indexOf(keyword)>-1) {
                  matches++;
                  break;
              }
          }
      }
      return matches == keywords.length;
   }
);
```

forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/9d097s4a/**

---

**OR**-filter (include rows where at least one of the search words is present). This is another approach, mostly an attempt to streamline [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25396710/1407478) above. Instead of playing with `oSearch` and hardcoded search terms, the default filtering event is replaced with an event that tokenizes the search phrase and then performs an advanced `fnFilter()`. As optional experiment, the search is now only performed when the user hits <kbd>enter</kbd> - it feels somehow more natural.

```
var input = $(".dataTables_filter input");
input.unbind('keyup search input').bind('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
       var keywords = input.val().split(' '), filter ='';
       for (var i=0; i<keywords.length; i++) {
           filter = (filter!=='') ? filter+'|'+keywords[i] : keywords[i];
       }            
       dataTable.fnFilter(filter, null, true, false, true, true);
       //                                ^ Treat as regular expression or not
    }
});
```

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/2p8sa9ww/**

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Although, your forked fiddle is not working as expected. If I search for `10 99` the search should yield rows 1, 5 and 6.

Comment: hey @SameerJoshi, well - if you expect rows 1,5 and 6 to be returned on 10 99, then it is not an AND search you want to perform, but a OR search? No rows matches both 10 and 99.

Comment: My bad. You are correct. I need an 'OR' search not an 'AND'. I have edited the question accordingly. Any idea how this can be managed?

Comment: where i add this $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push is it in jquery.dataTable.js or my js file?

Comment: @Borna, you can add it anywhere. Before or after you initialise the table, it does not matter (of course except that a filter only works when it is declared) `$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering` is a simple LIFO list where the last inserted filter is the first to be executed, and the first to be removed if you use `$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.pop()`  If you want a general AND filter as above, then I will suggest you add the filter in your js code just before your `$('#example').DataTable()`.

Comment: am using exactly ur code except here (aData[col].indexOf(keyword)>-1) {...i add if (aData[col][0].indexOf(keyword)>-1) { because i want to search that start with search word..it work in fiddle ..but in my js file it called aData[col][0]  is undefined .is it ok with yajra datatable?

Comment: @Borna, If I understand you correct, then you should use `aData[col].charAt(0) == keyword.charAt(0)` (or something similar, if you want to test on the first character) I dont know how excatly yajra dataTables output the javascript clientside, but it is jQuery dataTables and there should be no difference what so ever in how the plugin works, yajra dataTables is just a convenient wrapper for the plugin.

Comment: @davidkonrad when i try to use  two datatables ,it stop to show one datatable tbody datas but another datatable work

Comment: @Borna, yes - you are applying a general custom filter and both tables wll try to use it. It is a good question that is not directly addresed in the API - but you can use this solution mentioned by Allan Jardine -> https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/5228/tip-custom-filters-and-multiple-tables ...Simply use the `oSettings` object to check if it is the right table that is about to be filtered.  Have not tried it myself but it sounds as a good solution.

Comment: @Borna, cant you use `if (oSettings.sTableId == '#table_not_to_have_filter') return true` to exclude tables that not should use a certain custom filter ..?

Comment: i have two datatables in same page n i want both of them use same custom filter function. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39119015/how-to-change-yajra-datatable-search-filtering-system?noredirect=1#comment65589818_39119015

Comment: @davidkonrad where you refer to #your_input_text_field, I do not have one because I am using the DataTable's default search field, how might I add the OR-filter to the already existing DataTable's search field?

Comment: @Chisx, I really dont follow. Could you be more precise?

Comment: @davidkonrad Apologies I realized after some more testing that it is in fact changing the search field. No help needed now but thank you. Just trying to get fnfilter() working in the newest DataTables.

Answer (score 7):

Updated for Datatables 1.10

//Search field in new location

```
Table = $('#your_datatable').DataTable();
$('#your_input_text_field').keyup(function () {
    Table.search($(this).val()).draw();
})

////OR search (enabling regular expression search)
var input = $('#your_input_text_field');
input.unbind('keyup search input').bind('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var keywords = input.val().split(' '),
            filter = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
            filter = (filter !== '') ? filter + '|' + keywords[i] : keywords[i];
        }
        //true (param 2) turns regex on, false (param 3) turns smart search off
        Table.search(filter, true, false).draw();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I got this working by using regEx search. I used the following regEx to search throughout the table for keywords `10 99`

`^(?=.*?(10|99)).*?`

Forked fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/illuminatus/2j0Lz5or/6/

Ref: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/12062/filtering-jquery-datatable-using-regular-expression

Comment: This approach is mostly suitable when you have a custom input field for the search (eg not the built in input) and a custom event for preprocessing before manually performing the search. OR-filtering can be implemented several ways, have added a more "streamlined" version to my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

The same but triggering search on "every" key press instead of pressing enter:

```js
var dataTable = $('table').dataTable();
var input = $(".dataTables_filter input");
input.unbind('keyup search input').bind('keyup',
function(e) {
    if (input.val().length > 0) {
        var keywords = input.val().trim().split(' '), filter = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
            filter = (filter !== '') ? filter + '|' + keywords[i] : keywords[i];
        }
        dataTable.fnFilter(filter, null, true, false, true, true);
        //                                ^ Treat as regular expression or not                        
    } else if (input.val().length == 0) {
        dataTable.fnFilter(" ", null, true, false, true, true);
    }
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.6/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.6/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.6/css/dataTables.responsive.css">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.6/js/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>

<h5>OR SEARCH</h5>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>D</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>10</td></tr>
      <tr><td>0</td><td>5</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
      <tr><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
      <tr><td>2</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>10</td></tr>
      <tr><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>9</td><td>10</td></tr>
      <tr><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>99</td><td>0</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
var dataTable = $('#your_datatable').dataTable();
var input = $(".dataTables_filter input");
input.unbind('keyup search input').bind('keyup',
function(e) {
    if (input.val().length > 0) {
        var keywords = input.val().trim().split(' '), filter = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
            filter = (filter !== '') ? filter + '|' + keywords[i] : keywords[i];
        }
        dataTable.fnFilter(filter, null, true, false, true, true);
        //                                ^ Treat as regular expression or not                        
    } else if (input.val().length == 0) {
        dataTable.fnFilter(" ", null, true, false, true, true);
    }
});
```