# jquery datable modify search to not filter selected rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/32440/

I have a jquery datatable with a checkbox on each row.  I would like that if the checkbox on the row is selected then when using the searchbox the selected rows will not be hidden. so for example if John is selected  with the searchbox blank and then I type in the searchbox Fred, John remains visible in the datatable because he is selected.   so  searchbox filter does not apply to selected rows.

here is the javascript.

```
function employee(id, firstName, lastName, dept, active) {
  var self = this;
  this.id = id;
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.dept = dept;
  this.active = active;
}

function model() {
  var self = this;
  this.employees = [];
}

var mymodel = new model();

$(document).ready(function() {
  mymodel.employees.push(new employee('1', 'Clara', 'Dellinger', 'IT', false));
  mymodel.employees.push(new employee('2', 'John', 'Smith', 'HR', false));
  mymodel.employees.push(new employee('3', 'Fred', 'Jones', 'Finance', false));
  mymodel.employees.push(new employee('4', 'Mary', 'Jans', 'Finance', false));
  mymodel.employees.push(new employee('5', 'Bob', 'Jones', 'IT', false));
  mymodel.employees.push(new employee('6', 'Fred', 'Thebes', 'HR', false));
  mymodel.employees.push(new employee('7', 'Sally', 'Jane', 'HR', false));
  mymodel.employees.push(new employee('8', 'Patrick', 'Roberts', 'HR', false));
  mymodel.employees.push(new employee('9', 'Lisa', 'Myers', 'Lab', false));
  mymodel.employees.push(new employee('10', 'Roscoe', 'Coletrain', 'Security', false));
  var table = $('#mytable').DataTable({
    data: mymodel.employees,
    columns: [{
      data: 'active',
      render: function(data, type, row) {
        if (type === 'display') {
          return '<input type="checkbox" class="editor-active">';
        }
        return data;
      },
      className: "dt-body-center"
    }, {
      data: 'id'
    }, {
      data: 'firstName'
    }, {
      data: 'lastName'
    }, {
      data: 'dept'
    }],
    rowCallback: function(row, data) {
      // Set the checked state of the checkbox in the table
      $('input.editor-active', row).prop('checked', data.active);
    }
  });

  $('#mytable tbody').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e) {
    var active = $(this).prop('checked');
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var employee = table.row($row).data();
    employee.active = active;
    console.log(employee);
    table.row($row).data(employee).draw();
  });

});
```

here is the html

```
<table class="table" id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Select</th>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>First</th>
      <th>Last</th>
      <th>Dept</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you searching comm(,) like this Fred, John in search box you cannot like this?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying or asking. I am attempting to not have the searchbox perform a filter on rows of the table that have the checkbox selected. so if the checkbox is selected the row cannot be filtered out.

Comment: ok i got your point now Thanks

Comment: Try to look for "OR" Logic search
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382569/jquery-datatables-or-search-filter/25396710#25396710

Comment: thank you Offir Pe'er I think I got it working. here it is http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/32475/  If you mark you change your comment to an answer I can mark it correct.