# jQuery Datatables search single column with AND operator

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have table with a column that contains multiple values separated by comma. like this

```
| # |       Column Name          |
| 1 |1,5,18,24,29,36,41,57       |
| 2 |1,18,23,27,35,39,50,56,66   |
| 3 |1,101,                      |
```

I am using following line to filter it.

```
table.columns(1).search("1|23|27",true, false).draw();
```

This returns me all 3 columns. However I want it to return ONLY second row instead of all 3.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery DataTables 'OR' Search/ Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382569/jquery-datatables-or-search-filter)

Answer (score 0):

You could use following RegEx expression to achieve what you want:

```
(?=.*1)(?=.*25)(?=.*27)
```

Expression utilizing look-ahead assertion, which allows to implement logical AND.

Comment: Hi, i got a similar issue but this RegEx doesn't work for me. Is there some other possible solution? I have tried finding out everywhere but no luck.