# Search column using AND rather than OR

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have some code to search a column for multiple entries

```
table1.columns(16).search(myValues.replace(/,/g, '|'),true,false).draw();
```

My question is how I'd change this to search for `AND` instead of `OR`

So if I had 3 cells with the following values:

```
Advanced Car Driver,Advanced Motorcyclist,Armoured Land Rover
Advanced Car Driver,Advanced Motorcyclist
Advanced Car Driver
```

If my search string I passed through was `Advanced Car Driver,Advanced Motorcyclist` it would only bring back the first two cells

Alternatively if I searched just for `Advanced Car Driver,Armoured Land Rover` then it would just bring the first cell back

Comment: See this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382569/jquery-datatables-or-search-filter Not sure if it is a duplicate. I am afraid you cannot get around a custom filter. Be aware the answer is in 1.9.x notation, have not made a 1.10.x version; you can refer to the jQuery instance by `var jQueryInstance = $('#myAlreadyInitialisedDataTable').dataTable()`

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use regex option and look for values contains.

```
table1.columns(16).search(myValues).draw();
```

Comment: I'm afraid that returns nothing

Comment: what is the value of `myvalues` variable? can you share jsfiddle with your issue recreated?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you may have it reversed. The search() function uses AND by default with smart search, which is why the first two rows are selected (i.e. return rows with `Advanced Car Driver AND Advanced Motorcyclist` rather than returning rows with `Advanced Car Driver OR Advanced Motorcyclist` which would return all three). Nevertheless, you are correct in that you will need to use regex to change the search criteria to OR.

Maybe try formatting the string `"Advanced Car Driver|Advanced Motorcyclist"` and assigning it to `myValues` prior to passing it into the `search()` function.